Exploring options for non-tech business team to run selenium WebDriver C# tests
Non-technical business team need to run test automation scripts. I have created selenium WebDriver test automation scripts (NUnit framework) and test results reports generated with Extent report package. Test scripts are saved in Azure Dev Ops repository.  This is my first test automation project and haven’t explored the integrating selenium WebDriver with release builds yet.
I am looking for options for how business team can run the test scripts and view the html reports. Thanks and I am happy to share additional details if needed.

There are many docs and blogs talking about how to run selenium tests in Azure Pipelines. Please review them and ask more specific question if any.

Automating Selenium Tests in Azure Pipelines
UI test with Selenium
Continuous Testing with Selenium and Azure DevOps

